# Calculate row-by-row changes on a DataFrame where row data is a vector

Tags: python, dataframe

As an example:

```
import pandas as pd    
a = pd.Series([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
a

0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [4, 5, 6]
2    [7, 8, 9]
dtype: object
```

I am looking for the percentage change for each row to the row below, eg the result:

```
0                                  [-0.75, -0.6, -0.5]
1    [-0.42857142857142855, -0.375, -0.333333333333...
2                                                 None
dtype: object
```

I have this solution:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

pd.Series([ [ [ (xx-yy)/yy for xx,yy in zip(x,y)] if y is not None else None] 
       for x,y in zip(a,a.shift(-1))])
```

but this seems overly complex. I'd be grateful for a neater solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to use Series/DataFrames of lists. Your operation would be a simple [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) with a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
df.pct_change(-1)

#           0      1         2
# 0 -0.750000 -0.600 -0.500000
# 1 -0.428571 -0.375 -0.333333
# 2       NaN    NaN       NaN
```

If you really want a Series of lists, use a DataFrame as intermediate:

```
a = pd.Series([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
out = pd.DataFrame(a.tolist()).pct_change(-1).agg(list, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0                                  [-0.75, -0.6, -0.5]
1    [-0.4285714285714286, -0.375, -0.3333333333333...
2                                      [nan, nan, nan]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any particular reason why you do this with `pandas` instead of `numpy`?

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

-np.diff(a, axis=0) / a[1:]
```

```py
array([[-0.75      , -0.6       , -0.5       ],
       [-0.42857143, -0.375     , -0.33333333]])
```

Comment: I have an existing DataFrame (with other columns of data) and wanted to add another column for relative changes.

Comment: In general I agree with the answer from @mozway ... either convert your data to a DataFrame or a numpy-array instead of using a series of lists... it will make your life a lot easier!